# Render a block after 3 6 than 9 nodes

Tags: drupal, time, block

I'm working a Drupal 7 site. In which i have a page "Client stories", page is created with views module showing nodes' teaser view.

Now the requirement is that i have to show a single block multiple times on this page. 1st after 3 nodes then after 6 nodes then after 9 nodes and so on.. I thought a lot a logic but failed.

Anyone has any idea how can i achieve this? I have also looked over google but ended up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but this seems to be what you're looking for:
https://github.com/pedroposada/custom_views_nthrow
This is a Drupal 7 module for views, that exactly does what you need.

If you want to do it by yourself, here is a step by step solution, really easy! http://www.jasom.net/how-to-add-custom-code-adsense-after-first-row-in-drupal-7-and-drupal-8-views-one-line-solution

Make a custom .tpl for your views und use this code:

```
    <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
  <?php if ($id == 0 || $id == 5): ?>My custom code after first and sixth row in Drupal views<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Change the $id numbers to 2,5 and 8.

Comment: Hi @FNGR while this answer may be useful, please consider the following: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: HI @FlorianGerhardt, i edited my answer, hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

Think the easiest way is to override the view tpl (the style one), and add the logic there so instead of rendering all the "rows" in a roll, you output the block after every 3 nodes.